# Exchange Webservice Managed API - Lock appointment for deletion

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is it possible to lock an appointment created from code with the EWS, so the user of the exchange account can not move or change any information regarding the appointment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. Not from EWS, not from Outlook Object Model, not from Extended MAPI.

Comment: To bad, wanted to use the Outlook calendar to show work schedule for employees, combined with their own appoinments. The appoinments I wanted to lock are created/assigned and controlled by someone else in a different program. If the employee can then freely move them around the schedule in the external program will be different, thus making the idear pointless. :(